# Can't find my changes in Microsoft's Team Services (Git)

Tags: git, azure-devops, visual-studio-2017

I'm new to git and just migrated the project that I'm working on to a repository in microsoft's team services (xxxx.visualstudio.com).

Between my last commit and this one, I created a branch to work on a possible update, then switched back to master to fix a bug. After all changes were made, I commit and push to master, however, I can't find my commit in the history tab in team services, nor the changes in the code.

[image: History window on Team Services (Web) history panel]

I noticed on Visual Studio that the parent for my last commit is empty, may that be the problem?

[image: History window on Visual Studio]

What should I do?

Comment: Did you sync the changes with the VSTS git?  I am wondering if you only checked in the change locally and did not send it to 
VSTS

Comment: @KenTucker yes I did sync it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that my git configuration was wrong.

[image]

On Team Services -> Settings -> Repository Settings -> Remotes I noticed that I was pointing to my bit bucket remote server, once I removed the origin I was able to publish my local repository to my Team Services account by clicking with right mouse button on my local repository then selecting "publish to..."

Answer (score 0):

If `SemaphoreUpadte` is the new created branch, it seems you were not update on this branch but always worked on `master` branch: created `SemaphoreUpadte` branch at `ffc921db` and then commit changes `2cb07b05` and `0c65965b` on `master` branch.

Troubleshooting for not finding the latest commit on `master`:

1. Make sure your current branch was `master` and you pushed successful in VS. You can double check by switching to `master` branch, and check if the up arrow shows 0.

[image]

2. In VSTS History Tab, make sure the `master` branch was selected.

[image]

If both of the steps are working good, you should find the latest commit on master branch.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But my problem was my git configuration, check my answer.